# Cross thread operation while working event raised by other object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, thread-safety, multithreading

I have a class 'userdetails' which is having a event called 'detailschanged'. It will be raised whenever the user detail changes.
When i am creating a new object of 'userdetails' (objUserDetails) in my new form, i ll subscribe to event 'detailschanged' to indicate the user about the datachange.

```
objUserDetails.detailschanged += InformtoUser
```

InformtoUser is a method in new form. In InformtoUser method i am accessing form's control(say label's text property).
When the control is accessed I am getting 'Cross Thread Operation' error.
How to avoid this cross thread operation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI controls can only be updated from UI thread.
If you are working with WinForms you should do:

```
mycontrol.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
  mycontrol.Text="some text";
}));
```

And if you are in WPF then you should use the dispatcher:

```
myControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => myControl.Text = ""));
```

Comment: But i am creating that object in UI thread only. Then how it is giving cross thread??

Comment: Yes, all access to UI components should be done in UI thread not just creation :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is thread safety:

> Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state. Other thread-related bugs are possible, such as race conditions and deadlocks. It is important to make sure that access to your controls is performed in a thread-safe way.
>
> It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other than the one that created the control without using the Invoke method.

You need to use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) when making any cross-thread call to a Windows Forms control.

For example:

```cs
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

private void SetText(string text)
{
    if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
    {    
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.Text = text;
    }
}
```

or:

```cs
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    this.textBox.Text = "Some text here";
});
```

For more information, you should refer to **[How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)**.

Comment: But i am creating that object in UI thread only. Then how it is giving cross thread??